# Display value between two numbers

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a column in my table in MySQL named "month" and "month2", the month column has a value of "11" and month2 column has a value of "15". Is it possible to display the values between month (11) and month2 (15) ? I'm talking about displaying numbers 12,13 and 14. Thanks!

EDIT:

What if the numbers 12,13,14 are in a search field? for example the user search for day 14, and 14 is between month(11) and month2(15)??

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(range($month1 + 1, $month2 - 1) as $month) {
    echo $month;
}
```

Untested, and need some error checking, but may do the job.

Comment: why do you create an array with `range` to use `foreach` instead of going with a plain `for`? `for ($i = $month1 + 1; $i < $month2; $i++) { echo $i; }`

Comment: No particular reason, just felt like using a foreach and range. They both reduce down to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a loop.

```
for ($i = 11; $i < 15; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_field='somevalue'";
$result=mysql_query($sql); 
if(!$result){
  echo 'error occurred';
  die(mysql_error());
}

$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$month=$row['month'];
$month2=$row['month2'];

for($i=$month+1;  $i<$month2; $i++){
  echo $i."&nbsp;&nbsp;"
}
```