# Create a loop structure to display all integer values BETWEEN the smaller and larger number provided?

Tags: php

Working on a homework assignment and am stuck with this task: Create a loop structure to display all integer values BETWEEN the smaller and larger number provided.  Not looking for just an answer in code form.  Would appreciate an explanation as to how and why it works.

Data for the variables comes from users inputting a value between 1 and 100.  I assume I will need a loop that will start with the lower of the two variables, count until it reaches the higher of the two variables, echo each integer in between and stop running.  I am at a loss as to how to achieve this.  I will also need a loop that will display only integers at certain intervals between the two numbers, such as only the multiples of five.

EDIT: Here is my own solution, curious if this is the best method?  Seems simple enough.

```
if ( $num1 < $num2 )
for ($i=$num1+1; $i<$num2; $i++)
    echo $i . "<br />";
else
for ($i=$num2+1; $i<$num1; $i++)
    echo $i . "<br />";
```

Here is some of the assignment thus far:

```
<?php
//Assign user input to variables
$num1 = $_GET['firstNum'];
$num2 = $_GET['secondNum'];

//Determine if each number is odd or even, display results
if( $odd = $num1%2 )
    echo "First number is an ODD Number <br />";
else
    echo "First number is an EVEN Number </br />";
if( $odd = $num2%2 )
    echo "Second number is an ODD Number <br />";
else
    echo "Second number is an EVEN Number </br />";
//Determine if the first number is larger than, smaller than, or equal to the second number, display results
if ( $num1 == $num2 )
    echo "First number is equal to second number <br />";
elseif ( $num1 > $num2 )
        echo "First number is greater than second number <br />";
    else
        echo "First number is less than second number <br />";

//Create a loop structure to display all integer values BETWEEN the smaller and larger number provided

?>
```

Comment: what loop structures do you know? You can find some there : http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php

Comment: "I assume I will need a loop that will start with the lower of the two variables, count until it reaches the higher of the two variables, echo each integer in between and stop running." Correct. Now, which PHP book are you using? Have you read through the manual?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485993/display-value-between-two-numbers/

Comment: I think I found a solution after walking away for a minute, my question may have been premature.  Will post it momentarily.

Comment: It may be better to assign `$num1` and `$num2` as the smaller and larger number. That way, you need to write the for loop only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( $num1 < $num2 )
for ($i=$num1+1; $i<$num2; $i++)
echo $i . "<br />";
else
for ($i=$num2+1; $i<$num1; $i++)
echo $i . "<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

this may not perfectly fit your need. but hope this helps.

```
$num_small=$num1;
$num_large=$num2;
$multiply=1;
for ($i=$num_small; $num_large<=$i; $i+$multiply) {
  echo $i;
}
```